# to play sound for my  android application

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to load a sound effect which plays when a specific event happens.

For some reason I can hear the sound but it doesn't play the whole file and it brakes it in the middle.

My sound code:

```
public class SoundManager {

    private Context context;
    private int nudgeSound = R.raw.nudge;


    public SoundManager(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void playNudgeSound()
    {           
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, nudgeSound);

          mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

              @Override
              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                  mediaPlayer.reset();
              }

          });   
          mediaPlayer.start();

    }
}
```

my initialization:

```
    SoundManager soundManager = new SoundManager(this);
    soundManager.playNudgeSound();
```

Comment: Does it brake before playing the hole file if you don't call reset()?

Comment: yes it does... i do have a vibrate going on with it at the same time, but even when i'm disable it i still get the same brake..

Comment: There's a small possibility that there is something wrong with the audio file. Can you try it another way, such as with a sample app or via the browser?

Comment: Is the activity closing while the sound is playing? If the activity closes mid way only a portion of the sound will play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after few days of wondering around and lots of frustration i've found out that my problem was that the MediaPlayer.create() didn't had much time to load the file to memory...
it happened because create() and start() were called almost at the same time..

my recommendation is to load all your sound files when your Application is loading, and just call start() whenever you need them. build some kind of SoundManager class.

Thanks everyone ! hope it will help someone!

Comment: Glad to hear that you sorted it out

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever considered to use a SoundPool instead?! In my applications this works fine.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
int sound = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.beep, 1);
soundPool.play(sound, maxVolume, maxVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```